# [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.]

Tags: asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with a database in SQL Server 2008. I have created a virtual directory in IIS on the development system. I'm able to run the hosted application on the development machine. but if I try to access it using another system then raises the following exception:

`SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: One or more of your sql statements have incorrect syntax. To help you, we would need to see the code where it happens.

Comment: what is the query that you are trying to execute from the application

Comment: This could be a number of things including permissions and security related as well as the parts that @Anri and Sunny have mentioned. Can you "Attach to IIS" on Visual Studio on the dev machine and then try accessing on the remote machine?